# Proof that Linear Transformations $S:\Bbb R^m\mapsto\Bbb R^k$ and $T:\Bbb R^n\mapsto\Bbb R^m$ Satisfy $S(T(\vec x))=[S][T]\vec x$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Where $[S]$ is the matrix representation of the transform.

Theorems already established: Every linear transform $T(\vec x)$ can be written as $[T]\vec x$ where $\vec x$ is a vector that can be multiplied with matrix $[T]$

My proof goes like this and avoids the numerous sigmas that prof. used, but I am afraid of circular logic:

Consider $S(T(\vec x))$. Write $T(\vec x)=\vec z, \vec z\in\Bbb R^m$

Now consider $S(\vec z)$. By the theorem already established, $S(\vec z)=[S]\vec z$.

We already defined $\vec z$ to be equal to $[T]\vec x$. Back substitute to write:

$S(\vec z)=[S][T]\vec x$.

Then since z is also equal to $T(\vec x)$, rewrite the LHS as $S(T(\vec x))$. Now we have:

$S(T(\vec x))=[S][T]\vec x$, which is what we set out to prove.

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine!

Comment: The numerous sigmas proof, I think is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Overly wordy, but yes indeed.

When $S:\Bbb R^n\mapsto \Bbb R^k$, $T:\Bbb R^m\mapsto \Bbb R^n$, are linear transformations, then there exist matrices $[\mathbf S]\in\Bbb R^{k\times n}$ and $[\mathbf T]\in\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ enacting the transforms.   (As per the theorem established [add reference].)

Thus on any vector $\vec x\in \Bbb R^m$, we have: $S(T(\vec x))~{=~ [\mathbf S]\,T(\vec x) \\ =~ [\mathbf S][\mathbf T]\,\vec x  }$

$\blacksquare$